# FCM не приходит push когда приложение убито

Tags: android, firebase, fcm

Понимаю, что тема избитая, но все же
Есть задача принимать пуши, в идеале кастомизировать и показывать Notification.
Причем Notification показываем только когда приложение не в фоне
Тут начались проблемы, то никак не могу получить push если приложение было убито или не запускалось после перезагрузки, даже если пушицы содержит секцию notification, но при этом если приложение в фоне или беграунде все приходит. 
 Если я получу хотя бы один пушицы в баграунде, то все начинает нармально работать, даже при убитом приложении, при том шлю в push только data(Наверно запускается сервис, и пока он не умрет все работает хорошо)

Manifest

```
        <service
        android:name="zzz.firebase.fcm.AppFirebaseInstanceIDService"
        android:exported="false"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
</application>
```

FirebaseMessagingService

```
    override fun onMessageReceived(message: RemoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(message)
    Timber.e("push  ${message.data.map { (key, value) -> "$key::$value" }
        .joinToString("; ")}  ")
    Timber.e("push  ${message.getPushType()}  ${GoToTheShopApp.isAppForeground}")
    if (isAppForeground) showNotification(message)
}
```

Postman body

```
{ 
"to" : "sender_token",
"notification": {
     "title" : "title",
     "body"  : "body text"
},
"data": {
        "name": "Postman",
        "identificator": "PostmanUser",
        "type": "PushType"
```

}
}

Comment: Вы на своем телефоне тестируете приложение? я правильно понял, что пока приложение находится свернутым, все работает, как только вы "убиваете" приложение из списка многозадачности, push уведомления перестают приходить?

Comment: Да, тестировал на 2 реальных телефонах(android10) после перезагрузки телефона не приходят, а после смахивания в основном не работает

Comment: Ради интереса ставил на приложение галочку, автозагрузка
Тогда все пуши запускаются  на ура

Comment: Была подобная проблема, на андройде 4.2 все работало хорошо, а вот на 5.1, после того как "убью" переставало. ПРоблема заключалась в следующем, 4.2 был чистый андройд, а на 5.1 от асуса стояли доп. приложения, так вот, одно из этих приложений и ограничивало работу фоновых процессов приложений. В Xiaomi сейчас данная функция называется "Контроль фоновой активности", данный контроль управляется для каждого приложения. Чтобы проверить мою теорию, установите VM с чистым андройдом(без оболочек) и все должно работать)

Comment: токен FCM может меняться, причем он это делает регулярно особенно после ребута. поэтому когда у вас приложение запущено, токен обновляется, когда не запущено, а он изменился, то ессно не доходит ваш пуш. попробуйте посылать пуш в топик, а не на устройство. топик в фцм появится после первой подписки устройства любого, еще onMessageReceived() запускается в процессе фцм(похоже) когда ваше приложение не запущено, надо чтобы код внутри работал очень быстро, т.к. я замечал, что если не запускать фоновую службу и там и делать долгую обработку то его просто завершает по таймауту вызывающий процесс.

Comment: да токен может меняться, и на смене окна у меня есть метод
Хотя я его сравнивал и у меня он не менялся, если только приложение не удалить